# How to execute the rest of nsupdate in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

So I need to have a script that will execute the `nsupdate` command, to add a record the the ddns database:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
import sys
import os
import time
import subprocess

try:
        hostname = sys.argv[1]
        IP = sys.argv[2]
except Exception as e:
        print('Error: Please enter a number\n')

zone = hostname[-5:]
update = ''
if zone  == 'zone1':
        print('\nThis will be added to zone1\n')
        #add to zone 1
        update = 'update add ' + hostname + ' 86400' + ' A ' + IP
        os.system('nsupdate -k zone1.key')
        update = 'update add ' + hostname + ' 86400' + ' A ' + IP

if zone == 'zone2':
        print('This will be added to zone2')
        #add to zone 2
        os.system('nsupdate -k zone2.key')

#if statement to check IP address is in range

#update = 'update add ' + hostname + ' 86400' + ' A ' + IP
time.sleep(2)
os.system(update)
time.sleep(2)
os.system('send')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('quit')
#time.sleep(3)
print('\nHostname:')
print(hostname)
print('\nIP address: ')
print(IP)
print('\nZone: ')
print (zone)
```

Above is the code I'm currently working with, please ignore it if its badly written, dont write much python.
I find it executes the first `os.system` fine, but will not run the next three.
I believe that's because the command line changes from `#` to `>` but have got no clue how to still have it execute those commands.

Have tried `os.system` and `subprocess.run`/`call`
even tried call it all in one `os.system` by going `os.system('nsupdate; {update}; send; quit')`.

Any help would be great.